# Do I have firewire 1394a or 1394b? lspci dump inside

Tags: firewire

Trying to determine which firewire version I have in my laptop.  Here's lspci -vv:

```
05:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller (rev 30) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 5102
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast TAbort- TAbort- MAbort- SERR- PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
        Region 0: Memory at f6101000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Region 1: Memory at f6100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME+
        Capabilities: [80] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s 64ns, L1 1us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 16384 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 unlimited, L1 unlimited
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        Capabilities: [94] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: fffffffc  Data: 0000
        Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
        Kernel modules: firewire-ohci, ohci1394
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have a [JMicron JMB38X-series](http://www.jmicron.com/Product_JMB381.htm) 1394a Firewire 400 controller.